# Custom Wordpress Database Query

Tags: wordpress, search

I am trying to create a custom filter which would query the database in three parameters - post content, meta value and taxonomy term.

Here is the form code

```
 <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>/search-results">

 <div class="search_jobs">
 <?php do_action( 'job_manager_job_filters_search_jobs_start', $atts ); ?>

 <div class="item">
 <input type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="Keyword" />
 </div>

 <div class="item">

 <input type="text" name="location"  placeholder="All Locations" />
 </div>

<div class="item">
<label for="search_categories"><?php _e( 'Category', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?></label>
<?php wp_dropdown_categories( array( 'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_category', 'hierarchical' => 1, 'show_option_all' => __( 'All Job Categories', 'wp-job-manager' ), 'name' => 'search_categories', 'orderby' => 'name' ) ); ?>
</div>

<div class="search-s">
<input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search" />
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

This is the query I have so far

```
<?php
$s_key = $_GET['keyword'];
$s_loc = $_GET['location'];
$s_cat = $_GET['search_categories'];

global $wpdb;

$searchquery = $wpdb->get_results( 
"
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE 1

AND post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'job_listing'

AND post_content LIKE '%$s_key%' AND meta_value LIKE '%$s_loc%' 
"
);
?>
```

The important part is that keyword is just a plain text input field and it searches for keywords in the post content. It works fine this way.
Location is meta value and key is named _job_location.
Search categories is a dropdown of taxonomy terms. Taxonomy is called job_listing_category.
I need to have this query searching for all the parameters or for example just one if user decides to use just one field. After the query I have loop which works fine so I didn't paste it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing . ?

Comment: you need to add joining with post_meta & taxonomy tables for relation and search.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the provided variables and build the query depending on if the variable is passed:

```
$query = ' 1=1 ';
if($s_key){ $query .= " AND post_content LIKE '%$s_key%'"; }
if($s_loc){ $query .= " AND meta_value LIKE '%$s_loc%'"; }

global $wpdb;

$searchquery = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE {$query}");
```